# Error in paramiko: paramiko.transport: TypeError: long() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType'

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

Trying to build a self contained python script to connect to a server via paramiko with private key file and known_hosts stored in local directory. It connects but it keeps getting an error:

`paramiko.transport: TypeError: long() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType'`

I can find nothing in the docs or code on what is happening here.

```
client = paramiko.SSHClient()
paramiko.util.log_to_file('paramiko.log')
client.load_system_host_keys('known_hosts')
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.WarningPolicy())
client.get_host_keys().add(hostname, 'ssh-rsa', key)
client.connect(hostname, username='root', pkey=key)
print '\tconnected'
self.stdin, self.stdout, self.stderr = client.exec_command('/usr/local/sbin/comd')

client.close()
```

Logs:

```
DEB [20150123-12:33:23.334] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Switch to new keys ...
DEB [20150123-12:33:23.342] thr=2   paramiko.transport: Trying SSH key 992b10a56fa369fcc7d61b64f08a3d53
DEB [20150123-12:33:23.553] thr=1   paramiko.transport: userauth is OK
ERR [20150123-12:33:23.553] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Unknown exception: long() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType'
ERR [20150123-12:33:23.555] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Traceback (most recent call last):
ERR [20150123-12:33:23.556] thr=1   paramiko.transport:   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 1625, in run
ERR [20150123-12:33:23.556] thr=1   paramiko.transport:     self.auth_handler._handler_table[ptype](self.auth_handler, m)
ERR [20150123-12:33:23.556] thr=1   paramiko.transport:   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramiko/auth_handler.py", line 241, in _parse_service_accept
ERR [20150123-12:33:23.556] thr=1   paramiko.transport:     sig = self.private_key.sign_ssh_data(blob)
ERR [20150123-12:33:23.556] thr=1   paramiko.transport:   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramiko/rsakey.py", line 97, in sign_ssh_data
ERR [20150123-12:33:23.556] thr=1   paramiko.transport:     rsa = RSA.construct((long(self.n), long(self.e), long(self.d)))
ERR [20150123-12:33:23.557] thr=1   paramiko.transport: TypeError: long() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType'
ERR [20150123-12:33:23.557] thr=1   paramiko.transport:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check that `pkey` actually contains your private key. If not, load it with

```
pkey = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file("priv.key")
```

Also note that "host_keys" contains a list of public-keys for remote hosts. Your code actually pushes your private key into the "known_hosts" db that is used for host key verification. Please remove this line or add the remote hosts pubkey there.

```
client.get_host_keys().add(hostname, 'ssh-rsa', peer_pubkey)
```